# FunctionTimer dose not exist in the current context

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a code exactly like I saw on YouTube video
to load scenes with transition in Unity.
but it keeps getting an error that the "FunctionTimer does not exist in the current context"
This is my code.
What is wrong? and how can I fix it
thanks :)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private GameObject _startingSceneTransition;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _endingSceneTransition;

    private void Start()
    {
        _startingSceneTransition.SetActive(true);
        FunctionTimer.Create(DisableStartingSceneTransition, timer: 5f);
    }

    private void DisableStartingSceneTransition()
    {
        _startingSceneTransition.SetActive(false);
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            _endingSceneTransition.SetActive(true);
            FunctionTimer.Create(LoadNextLevel, timer: 1.5f)
;            
        }
    }

    private static void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("menu");
    }


}
```

I tried to switch the functionTimer with other time functions but it doesn't help

Comment: what is "FunctionTimer"?  as its certainly not defined here

Comment: Give us a link to the tutorial. You either skipped something from it or it is a multipart tutorial and you're missing a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty much what it says on the tin. Whatever "FunctionTimer" is supposed to be (Presumably a class/script), it is not there.

If you're following a tutorial I would re-watch it and see if you missed anything.

However if you just want to load a scene with a transition this should work:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject startingSceneTransition;
    [SerializeField] GameObject endingSceneTransition;

    enum TransitionType
    {
       STARTING,
       ENDING
    }

    void Start()
    {
       StartCoroutine(DoTransition(TransitionType.STARTING);
    }

    Ienumerator DoTransition(TransitionType Type)
    {
       switch(Type)
       {
           case TransitionType.STARTING:
               startingSceneTransition.SetActive(true);
               yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
               startingSceneTransition.SetActive(false);
           break;
           case TransitionType.ENDING:
               endingSceneTransition.SetActive(true);
               yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
               SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

Bear in mind you will either need to add `DontDestroyOnLoad(this)` to the `Start` Method of that script, or have another GameObject with that script attached in the Menu scene for this to work.